# Trying to run C2DM sample project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, android-emulator

Hi am a Beginner trying to develop C2DM based Apps on Android,

Referencing this: http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug.html

and try to get the same output

I initially got some errors, especially request-factoryapt.jar is missing in gwt-2.2.

so i downloaded it manually & added that to gwt folder.  I have signed in to my gmail account in the emulator, and when I press the button and wait for response....

After some time it shows network time out error

But when I checked console, I got this error:

> Unable to find 'com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/RequestFactory.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

Does anyone knows what is this??

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this link
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

I have successfully implemented C2DM in two different application.

Hope this help you